# Train on transformed output

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras

I have a recurrent neural network model that maps a `(N,)` sequence to a `(N,3)` length sequence. My target outputs are actually `(N,N)` matrices. However, I have a deterministic function implemented in numpy that converts `(N,3)` into these `(N,N)` matrices in a particular way that I want. How can I use this operation in training? I.e. currently my neural network is giving out `(N,3)` sequences, how do I perform my function to convert it to `(N,N)` on these *before* calling `keras.fit`?

Edit: I should also note that it is much harder to do the reverse function from `(N,N)` to `(N,3)` so it's not a viable option to just convert my target outputs to the `(N,3)` output representations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Lambda](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda) layer as the last layer of your model:

```
def convert_to_n_times_n(x):
    # transform x from shape (N, 3) to (N, N)

transformation_layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(convert_to_n_times_n)
```

You probably want to use "`tf`-native methods" within your function as much as possible to avoid unnecessary conversions of tensors to numpy arrays and back.

If you only want to use the layer during training, but not during inference, you can achieve that using the functional API:

```
# create your original model (N,) -> (N, 3)
input_ = Input(shape=(N,))
x = SomeFancyLayer(...)(input_)
x = ...
...
inference_output = OtherFancyLayer(...)(x)

inference_model = Model(inputs=input_, outputs=inference_output)

# create & fit the training model
training_output = transformation_layer(inference_output)
training_model = Model(inputs=input_, outputs=training_output)

training_model.compile(...)
training_model.fit(X, Y)

# run inference using your original model
inference_model.predict(...)
```